# How can I tell which style is overriding another?

Tags: css, overriding, margin

I've searched, and the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412561/in-firebug-how-to-tell-what-is-overriding-a-style) seem to state that I should look above the crossed-out property to find the style that is overriding it. However, there ARE no styles above it in my case (see screenshot.) The style I'm concerned with is the .sponsorFooter table margin-bottom property. Where else should I be looking for something that's overriding that property?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Margins can be effectively overridden by contained/containing elements, due to "margin collapse". Try inspecting the children and possibly ancestors to see if this is what's happening.

Comment: Also on some browsers the `!important` attribute is considered which can sometimes override styles above it.

Answer (score 3):

Look for an !important flag in the css.  That will show up lower in the list, but override above.